# Web Server Monitoring Tools or software?

Tags: performance, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)
>   [Recommended website performance monitoring services?](https://serverfault.com/questions/4968/recommended-website-performance-monitoring-services)

I am looking for tools or software to monitor a web server.  Most importantly is that a notification be generated if the webserver, or site(s) running on the webserver, is offline (or down) for whatever reason.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like it should be asked on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wasitup.com/ is a fantastic service that should do the trick

Comment: But you'll likely outgrow it very soon - have a look at Nagios, cacti, munin...