# Recommendation for notification service when web server is down

Tags: web-server, monitoring

Can anyone recommend a good third party service that can notify you when your webserver is down?

Comment: duplicate? http://serverfault.com/questions/66897/advice-needed-for-monitoring-a-website

Comment: and similar to this SU q - http://superuser.com/questions/19126/are-there-any-tools-to-periodically-check-if-a-web-site-is-available/

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/1014/can-anyone-recommend-a-website-monitoring-service

Comment: Warren, could it be that you are hinting that posters should do a search before posting? What a novel idea.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I signed up for a [Pingdom](http://pingdom.com/) account a few days ago for a new site, and have found it to be really good. I signed up for their "Basic" Account, which includes 5 checks, 20 SMS alerts (could be higher) and unlimited emails for $9.95/month. I haven't been able to test how effective it is at alerting me when the server is down, as I have luckily not had any downtime on my site.

Comment: +1. We rely on Pingdom for monitoring a pretty high-profile web site. It never let us down.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple service:

Down Notifier
http://downnotifier.appspot.com/

1) it's free!
2) it's easy to start (10 seconds to subscribe to notification)
3) it's really easy! no need to register.

Answer (score 1):

AlertFox offers web monitoring plus web [transaction monitoring](http://wiki.alertfox.com/Transaction_Monitoring). It runs the tests in real IE and Firefoxm, and you receive a screenshot of the site when an error is detected - very useful. It proved useful to convince our sys admin that there was indeed an error on "his" server (php update bug) :D

Answer (score 0):

https://www.alertsite.com for example, but usually these are not for free. Actually if somebody can recommend a free solution i am also interested.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Watchmouse](http://www.watchmouse.com/en/). It costs about $50 a month to monitor 2 IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

[Montastic](http://montastic.com/) gives you some very basic but free monitoring.