# What do you use for 3rd party monitoring?

Tags: networking, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone recommend a website monitoring service?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014/can-anyone-recommend-a-website-monitoring-service)

What do you use for website/service monitoring, and notification from a 3rd party?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a more complex website (which I define as a site with more "stuff" that can break, such as Javascript, AJAX, Flash,...) , consider adding real user monitoring (RUM) to the mix. That is transaction monitoring using real web browsers like IE and Firefox.

We use [AlertFox](http://www.alertfox.com/). They also have a useful free plan to get started:
http://www.alertfox.com/free-website-monitoring/

Other good options for RUM are Keynote or Gomez, but they are "high end" (read: expensive).

Answer (score 2):

I like [Uptime Robot](http://uptimerobot.com/). Lots of notification options (SMS, e-mail, Twitter ...), up to 50 sites/services, and free.